# XP Right Click doesn't work for multiple selection

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, autohotkey, right-click

When I right click on a text file and select 'Open' it opens the file in notepad. But when I click multiple text files then select 'Open' nothing happens. Can someone help me on this? If it could be fixed it would be answer for 'Autohotkey right click not working on multiple files'. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Not all underlying windows programs allow you to select/open multiple files .....Anyway, how about upgrading from XP since it is now out of support and very vulnerable.

Comment: Will upgrading from XP help on this issue? If then I will upgrade it because I normally don't store any valuable information in my PC to be vulnerable.